# How can I incorporate a categorical variable with ~200 levels in a nonlinear mixed effects model in R?

Tags: r, categorical-data, nlme, random-effects

I am trying to fit a nonlinear mixed effects model with a categorical variable genotype that has around 200 levels.

So this is the linear version of the model.

`mlinear <- lmer(WUE ~ moisture * genotype + (1|pot), data = d8)`

Now I'm trying to make the same model, but with a logistic function instead of linear

`mlogistic <- nlme(WUE ~ SSlogis(moisture, Asym, xmid, scal), data = d8, fixed = Asym + xmid + scal ~ 1, random = Asym + xmid + scal~1|pot)`

Problem is, now I don't know how to incorporate genotype into this nonlinear model. Asym, xmid, and scal parameters should be able to vary between each genotype. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Ben Bolker’s notes on GLMMs with many-level categorical predictors may also be relevant: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/109258_9fd5c76643f24ec2894a6a421a4852fe.html

Comment: It’s not clear to me what your specific question is. eg, is it “how do I specify the same multi-level model as logistic instead of linear?” in which case, see my answer below; or is it, “how should I specify a logistic model for a continuous outcome?” in which case, I think my answer would still apply, but I wouldn’t swear to it, and you may want to ask at cross validated; or is it, how should I treat a large categorical predictor in a multilevel model? In which case, it would be helpful to say more about what problems you’ve had with approaches you’ve tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you’re using `lme4::lmer` for your linear model and `nlme::nlme` for the logistic? If you use `lme4` for both, you should be able to keep the same model specification, and use `lme4::glmer` with `family = binomial` for the logistic model. The whole idea behind a GLM with a link function is that you shouldn’t have to do anything different with your predictor vs a linear model, as the link function takes care of that.

```
library(lme4)

mlinear <- lmer(WUE ~ moisture * genotype + (1|pot), data = d8)

mlogistic <- glmer(WUE ~ moisture * genotype + (1|pot), family = binomial, data = d8)
```

All that being said, how is `WUE` measured? You probably want to use either a logistic model (if binary) or linear (if continuous), not both.

Comment: WUE is continuous (water use efficiency of a plant). So the data is not binomial.

Comment: Since my WUE responses are almost alway curved, I'm trying to fit a logistic function instead of a linear one.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer by @zephryl, who has explained how you can do this,  I would like to focus on:

> Since my WUE responses are almost alway curved, I'm trying to fit a logistic function instead of a linear one.

Fitting a logistic *model* does not really make sense here. The distribution of `WUE` is not relevant. It is the conditional distribution that matters, and we typically assess this by inspecting the residuals. If the residuals show a nonlinear pattern then there are several ways to model this including

- transformations
- nonlinear terms
- splines